# Hadoop performance problems because of too many nodes?

Tags: performance, hadoop, bigdata

i heard that hadoop can get performance problems if you run broad queries because too many nodes can be involved?

Can anyone verify or falsify this statement?

Thanks!
BR

Answer (score 0):

The namenode has performance problems if you add **too many files** as it must store all file locations in memory. You can optimize this by periodically creating larger archives. For example, daily database dumps becomes monthly/yearly compressed archives that are still in a processable format

HDFS datanodes are just a filesystem and scale linearly. Adding more NodeManager nodes overall has no negative consequences, and YARN has been reported as running up to 1000 nodes, I would suggest using standalone clusters if you actually needed more than that.

As with any distributed system, you need to optimize network switching and system monitoring, but those are operational performance problems not specific to Hadoop